# AutoResetEvent accumulative Sets()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

I've written this code as proof of concept in order to check a problem I'm experimenting with my current project.

```
var sleeper = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        sleeper.Set();
        sleeper.Set();
        sleeper.Set();

        var ix = 0;
        while(true) {
            sleeper.WaitOne();
            Console.Write(ix++);
        }
```

Surprisingly (at least for me) I'm not getting the result I expected.
I expected a `012` being printed in the console but only `0` is printed.

- What am I misunderstanding ?
- Which might be the best way to solve this problem and get the expected result?

Comment: A call to `Set()` when the `AutoResetEvent` is already in a signaled state does nothing. You probably want to look at using a `Semaphore` or `SemaphoreSlim` which maintains such a count.

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually output for your code is `0`
2. AutoResetEvent does not have a memory, it is either signalled or not. And you're waiting on it after it has been signalled. The sequence of events in your case:

   - create AutoResetEvent (state = 0)
   - signal AutoResetEvent (state = 1)
   - signal AutoResetEvent (state = 1)
   - signal AutoResetEvent (state = 1)
   - start waiting on the event (process the current signalled state of 1 and switch it to 0)
   - go on waiting on the event

As mentioned in msdn AutoResetEvent [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Also, if Set is called when there are no threads waiting and the
>   AutoResetEvent is already signaled, the call has no effect.

3. To observe the desired behavior you need a second Thread (as AutoResetEvent is created for inter-thread communication).

Something like this should work for you

```
private static AutoResetEvent sleeper;

static void Main()
{
    sleeper = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
    t.Start();

    var ix = 0;
    while(true) 
    {
        sleeper.WaitOne();
        Console.Write(ix++);
    }
}

static void ThreadProc()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    sleeper.Set();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    sleeper.Set();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    sleeper.Set();
}
```

4. Please note, that AutoResetEvent does **not** guarantee that it' will process 3 events for the following code

   ```
   sleeper.Set();
   sleeper.Set();
   sleeper.Set();
   ```

as mentioned in its' [description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)
Hence the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` bits.

> There is no guarantee that every call to the Set method will release a
>   thread. If two calls are too close together, so that the second call
>   occurs before a thread has been released, only one thread is released.
>   It is as if the second call did not happen.

Comment: Completely true! the output is 0! I'm going to fix it ;)